# Make 'Code Jumper' extension (its source-code) work with Vb.Net Modules

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

### SCENARIO

---

**[Code Jumper](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ab43a471-b840-4d81-ad6f-c9f350cfcd16)** is a time-saver extension/plugin for **Visual Studio** that adds a kind of navigation panel to easily jump between the members of your code with a single click.

For big APIs it's really useful because it avoids scrolling thousands of lines, opening #regions, hidding Xml documentation, searching for a method or member name, etc... its a must-have extension, because It really saves a lot of time:

[image]

### PROBLEM

---

**Code Jumper** has one big problem for my needs, it can't parse Vb.Net Modules, no matter what says in the product description, because the reality is that it can't (its written by a C# guy so maybe he didn't knew the existance of Modules...)

When opening a module, the window of **Code jumper** is empty, any member is shown.

### QUESTION

---

**[Here](https://codejumper.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)** is the downloadable source-code of **Code Jumper**, written in C#.

What modifications I need to do to make it work with Vb.Net Modules?.

### OPTIONAL QUESTION

---

Someone knows a similar and better extension than **Code Jumper**?.

### RESEARCH

---

I think this is the most relevant code, in `DocumentParser.cs` file:

```
public void RecurseCodeElements(CodeElements elements, CodeElementAggregate aggregate) {

    if (elements == null)
        return;
    _recurseCount++;

    if (_recurseCount % 2 == 0) {
        if (ParserProgress != null)
            _appConfig.elementView.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => ParserProgress(this)));
    }

    foreach (CodeElement element in elements) {

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);

        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass) {
            RecurseCodeElements(GetMembers(element), aggregate.Add(element));
        }

        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementInterface) {
            RecurseCodeElements(GetMembers(element), aggregate.Add(element));
        }

        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementStruct) {
            RecurseCodeElements(GetMembers(element), aggregate.Add(element));
        }

        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementNamespace) {
            RecurseCodeElements(GetMembers(element), aggregate);
        }

        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementEnum) {
            RecurseCodeElements(GetMembers(element), aggregate.Add(element));
        }

        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction ||
            element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementProperty ||
            element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementVariable ||
            element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementDelegate ||
            element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementEvent)
        {
            var func = element as CodeFunction;
            aggregate.Add(element);
        }
    }
}

private CodeElements GetMembers(CodeElement element) {

    if (element == null)
        return null;

    if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementNamespace) {
        return (element as CodeNamespace).Members;
    }

    if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass) {
        return (element as CodeClass).Members;
    }

    if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementInterface) {
        return (element as CodeInterface).Members;
    }

    if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementEnum) {
        return (element as CodeEnum).Members;
    }

    if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementStruct) {
        return (element as CodeStruct).Members;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I tried to add an additional condition for **[vsCMElement.vsCMElementModule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.vscmelement.aspx)**, however, it still don't work, and I 'm not sure whether I'm on the right direction:

```
public void RecurseCodeElements(CodeElements elements, CodeElementAggregate aggregate) {

    if (elements == null)
        return;
    _recurseCount++;

    if (_recurseCount % 2 == 0) {
        if (ParserProgress != null)
            _appConfig.elementView.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => ParserProgress(this)));
    }

    foreach (CodeElement element in elements) {

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);

        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass) {
            RecurseCodeElements(GetMembers(element), aggregate.Add(element));
        }

        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementModule) {
            RecurseCodeElements(GetMembers(element), aggregate.Add(element));
        }

        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementInterface) {
            RecurseCodeElements(GetMembers(element), aggregate.Add(element));
        }

        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementStruct) {
            RecurseCodeElements(GetMembers(element), aggregate.Add(element));
        }

        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementNamespace) {
            RecurseCodeElements(GetMembers(element), aggregate);
        }

        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementEnum) {
            RecurseCodeElements(GetMembers(element), aggregate.Add(element));
        }

        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction ||
            element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementProperty ||
            element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementVariable ||
            element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementDelegate ||
            element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementEvent)
        {
            var func = element as CodeFunction;
            aggregate.Add(element);
        }
    }
}

private CodeElements GetMembers(CodeElement element) {

    if (element == null)
        return null;

    if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementNamespace) {
        return (element as CodeNamespace).Members;
    }

    if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementModule) {
        return (element as CodeClass).Members;
    }

    if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass) {
        return (element as CodeClass).Members;
    }

    if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementInterface) {
        return (element as CodeInterface).Members;
    }

    if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementEnum) {
        return (element as CodeEnum).Members;
    }

    if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementStruct) {
        return (element as CodeStruct).Members;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get it to compile, but if you look at all references for `CodeElementType.Class`, almost all of them need to be "duplicated" with `CodeElementType.Module`, especially in `IsStackableElement`, probably answering your question.

---

Partial code to explain the required modifications:

```
public void RecurseCodeElements(CodeElements elements, CodeElementAggregate aggregate) {
    // ...
    foreach (CodeElement element in elements) {
        // ...
        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementModule) {
            RecurseCodeElements(GetMembers(element), aggregate.Add(element));
        }
        // ...
    }
}

private CodeElements GetMembers(CodeElement element) {
    // ...
    if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementModule) {
        return (element as CodeClass).Members;
    }
    // ...
}
public bool IsStackableElement {
    get
    {
        if (IsRoot) 
            // ...
            return (ElementType == CodeElementType.Class || ElementType == CodeElementType.Module || ... )
            // ...
    }
}

public static CodeElementType GetElementType(CodeElement element) {
    switch (element.Kind) {
        // ...
        case vsCMElement.vsCMElementModule:
            return CodeElementType.Module;
        // ...
    }
}

public void Draw() {
    // ...
    if (ElementType == CodeElementType.Module) {
        _elementStackPanel.Background = _appConfig.ClassBackgroundBrush;
    }
    // ...
}

public void Update() {
    // ...
    if (ElementType == CodeElementType.Module)
    {
        ElementLabel.AddExpander(_elementStackPanel);
        ElementLabel.AddPictureToSingleGrid(ElementInfo.ElementImage);
        ElementLabel.AddPictureToSingleGrid(ElementInfo.Accessibility.AccessibilityImage);
        ElementLabel.AddText(ElementInfo.Name, _appConfig.ClassTextBrush, _appConfig.HyperlinkTextImageSpacer, FontWeights.Bold);
    }
    // ...
}

private bool GetElementInfo() {
    // ...
    if (ElementInfo.ElementType == CodeElementType.Module) {
        ElementInfo.ElementImage = _appConfig.GetImage("staticclass");
    }
    // ...
}

private void ParseCodeElement() {
    // ...
    if (ElementInfo.ElementType == CodeElementType.Module)
    {
        ElementInfo.IsStackable = true;
        var codeClass = (CodeClass)Original;
        var codeClass2 = (CodeClass2)Original;
        ElementInfo.Accessibility = new AccessibilityContainer(_appConfig, codeClass.Access);
        ElementInfo.IsStatic = true;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I will try what you mentioned, thanks for answer!.About compiling it,I don't know what problem you found,but I also found problems to compile the first time,maybe this solves your problem: Change the targeting framework to 4.5 (for whatever reason in NetFx 4.0 it can't find the VS assemblies on my PC),If any **VisualStudio.xxxx.dll** reference is failing to be located,delete it and re-reference it from the Visual Studio's public assemblies directory (its on the Visual Studio Installation directory) or from GAC directory (if found there).PS: The VS SDK need to be installed to proceed compiling.